# Integration Question

Tags: calculus, integration

If

$$\int_{0}^1 f(x)-2g(x) dx = 6 $$

And

$$\int_{0}^1 2f(x)+2g(x) dx = 9 $$

What's

$$\int_{0}^1 f(x)-g(x) dx $$

?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it, instead of posting another answer saying thanks. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 5):

It is a system of linear equations :

You could just write $a = \int_0^1 f(x)$ and $b = \int_0^1g(x)$, and then you just need to solve :
$$\begin{cases} a - 2b = 6 \\ 2a + 2b = 9\end{cases}$$

To get both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \frac{2}{3}(f(x)-2g(x)) + \frac{1}{6}(2f(x)+2g(x)) = f(x)-g(x). $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** Can you write $A-B$ as a linear combination of $A-2B$ and $2A+2B$?

**Hint 2:** Integration is a linear operation on its integrand.